# Why virtual functions defy access specifiers ? C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, virtual-functions, access-specifier

let's assume u have a class base and class A which inherits from base . base have a declaration of a pure virtual functions called getValue() which is public , and A contains the definition(implementation) of the functions which is set as private .
When trying to use the function  getValue() from base reference or pointer (base& /base*) to an A object it access it even though it's declared as private

Comment: Could you show us a [mcve] of code that illustrates this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in C++, virtuality and access are orthogonal concerns. When the compiler sees a `base*` or `base&` and it needs to call `getValue` on it, then it's sufficient that the function is accessible in `base`.

The fact that `A` declares its (overriding) `getValue` as `private` is irrelevant. After all, how could it be relevant? When `base.getValue()` or `base->getValue()` is called, you don't **know** that you might be dealing with an `A`. That's the whole point of object-oriented programming in the first place!

---

This does not mean that it's good style to vary access specifiers within a class hierarchy, though, because it can be confusing. In fact, you should split your `getValue` into two different functions, one being virtual and the other one non-virtual.

Long story: C++ behaves very different from other popular programming languages here, because it actually allows and encourages **private virtual** functions. Virtual member functions should be private by default, and public member functions should be non-virtual by default, and call the private virtual ones if necessary. (The only exception is the destructor, of course.) Herb Sutter once called this the [Non-Virtual Interface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    int getValue() const
    {
        int const value = doGetValue();
        if (value < 0)
        {
            // error
        }
        return value;
    }

private:
    virtual int doGetValue() const = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
private:
    int doGetValue() const override
    {
        return 123;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* ptr = new A; // use std::unique_ptr in real code
    std::cout << ptr->getValue() << "\n";
    delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: thank's for the answer but I got some trouble understanding these :                                 - what is std::unique_ptr  ?         -why create const value can't u use directly doGetValue() ? -Why do I need to make 2 functions one virtual and the other one not ? and thank's in advance

Comment: @MekacherAnis Re: `std::unique_ptr`: cannot explain in comment, please search in Google. Re "why create const value": better style. Re: "why make two functions": please read the article that I linked.